# How to use viewHolder pattern to keep UI elements on scroll in listView?

Tags: java, android, listview

I am looking into using the viewHolder pattern for making my UI elements not get reset to the default when my listview is scrolled. After looking into it Im not sure how to go about this. Im not even sure if my existing code will even allow me to use viewHolder pattern. I am a beginner so please elaborate and do not skip the details. Thank you

MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ArrayList<String> Chores = new ArrayList<>();
        Chores.add("");

        final ListAdapter MyAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, Chores);
        ListView listViewObject = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.customListView_ID);
        listViewObject.setAdapter(MyAdapter);

        listViewObject.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                    String ChoreString = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                }
            }

        );
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ID);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Chores.add("");
                ((ArrayAdapter)MyAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static com.example.emilythacker.chorelist.R.id.textView_ID;

class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList choreText) {
        super(context, R.layout.custon_listview_row, choreText);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.custon_listview_row, parent, false);

        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) customView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_ID);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) customView.findViewById(textView_ID);

        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //what happens when textView is clicked
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();
                final EditText input = new EditText(getContext());
                input.setHint("hint");
                alertDialog.setView(input);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Set Chore");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Alert message to be shown");
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                //this will set text to "hello" only if user does not enter anything into input
                                //textView.setText("hello");

                                //this also will only work if there is no input entered into input...wich will change textView into empty space
                                textView.setText(input.getText().toString());

                                //works the same with or without dialog.dismiss();
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.clock);
        return customView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html) tutorial really helpful when learning to use the ViewHolder Pattern. It is pretty clear in explaining how to use it, but feel free to ask if you feel stuck.

Answer (score 0):

When you are performing some change to any list Item we should call notifyDataSetChanged(),so that the listview gets updated.

Answer to your question:
call notifyDataSetChanged() in textview.onClickListener() method after updating the text.

Better to shift to RecyclerView, In this when we add new item we can just call notifyItemAdded(position) which will refresh only the view at that position but not the whole. 
And when we update any item we can call notifyItemChanged(position).